# How do I recover my Gmail folders after I emptied them by accident?

Tags: gmail, google-account

Can I get my Gmail folders back? I bought a new Android tablet and accidentally deleted them into the recycle bin and emptied them.

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to Labels ... Gmail still has all your mails under "All mail" , maybe if you setup some smart filters and tick the box to also process existing mails you can restore large parts of your original labels.